# Executing a parallel task that might finish after return in Python

Tags: python, flask, parallel-processing

My REST request in Python, using Flask, requires two actions with databases that might take a while.

In one hand I want to answer what the user search for in his request. On the other, I want to register that search. I'd like to return the search even when I did not yet register the search.

The code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
    @app.route("/dictionary/<string:word>", methods=["GET"]
    def search_word(word):
        register_word(word)
        return find_word(word)
```

As said, how can I make `register_word(word)` and `find_word(word)` run in parallel and return the result of `find_word(word)` even if the other one hasn't finished yet.

Comment: Check out `multiprocessing` (python 2) and `asyncio` (python 2 or 3).

Comment: You can try using a task queue for that. [Celery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/celery/) is a popular choice and well-documented also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a thread for `register_word` function:

```
from flask import current_app

def register_word_async(app, word):
    with app.app_context():
        register_word(word)  # call your function

def call_register_word(word):
    # ...
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    thr = Thread(target=register_word_async, args=[app, word])
    thr.start()
    return thr

@app.route("/dictionary/<string:word>", methods=["GET"]
def search_word(word):
    call_register_word(word)
    return find_word(word)
```

While your `find_word` search at the same time `register_word` will run.

Comment: I suppose `word_async_register` and `register_word_async` should really be the same, aren't they?

Comment: While this should work, there can be a problem: If the UWSGI Host decides to terminate the process, your function can get stopped in mid-execution. The problem here is that flask has no control over its execution environment since that is USWGIs job. Best would be to just send a short message (e.g. via RabbitMq, Celery etc.) to a secondary service which can execute your long-running request